NEO-6M GPS module loses its accuracy on arduino uno
I have a NEO-6M GPS module and I want to use it for date,location and time.
Now, when the NEO-6M is set default to 115200 baud rate and when I use ttl converter to get signals from the GPS module it works just fine but when I try to use Arduino Uno and read signals from it, it sends garbage values.
$GNGGA,114213.000,2238.34233,N,07549.90950,E,1,17,0.8,535.6,M,0.0,M,,*78
$GNGLL,2238.343,595,4.0@6$SA00,6,4,,88.E$SA00169,,,,,8.0$SA779,,,88.D$S410,,,2,,,,,3314
G,,,12,0,,9,96,62
GS,419,255373,2557
G44,,0,1,0,*
D,1,,3,050218736,54
BV,89,4,,1,,33235728$S207,.32,8837202
LV25,,9*
NC430,843041000439,*GT.,M.N.K*
NA430,,200
GT11,TAK
$GNGGA,114214.000,2238.34233,N,07449.91952,E,0,17,0.8,535.6,M,0.0,M,,*7D
$GNGLL,2238.343,595,4.0,3"SA0066,4,,88.E$SA,0169,3,,,860GSA779,,,8,.D$S411,,,2,,2,,73,4
G,1,1286409016127$G4,292,,0,234,,0,
GV,,1,6746,8
BV,06312,,,,31,13328$S2,17520566,,7,,226
G,1,,93,2,,2,,06*
LV2,,,9*
N,440,843049200409,*
N,4,,0,0,2$Z120,,24,*GX11,T K
$GNGGA,114315.000,2238.34260,N,07549.91955,E,1,17,0.8,535.9,M,0.0,M,,+72
$GNGLL,2238.3460595110A4
A,34,,1,,.,,6
BA369,,,26,18,*
LA,,9,,,1016
GV,412011,6210,25F$S41005007,,3,,,,*
PV34,,,6,1,,,,8,4A$S4,33379262D$S2,0432931,3,56854
BV,89746,,,233,,2,6
L,1,,03,2,,2,9,6*
LV259,9*
N,450,34,041509.09,*
N,4,08,6,2$D12.,,24,*$P,,,AEO*

I want to lower the baudrate of the GPS module to 9600 but I can't seem to find any way to do It.
The connection to the rx and tx pins is very very short so I don't think that it is causing the problems.
THe code
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  // Begin serial communication with the PC
  Serial1.begin(115200);  // Start software serial for GPS module at 9600
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial1.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial1.read());  // Forward GPS data to the Serial Monitor
  }
}


You can configure it. Yes, you must send config data to 11520, until the system will be able to read you command (or just an hard reset, or the other port). But if device support such baud, it should be able to send data without problems. Are you sure the problem is not on Arduino side (you may need optimized code)

Also note: there is a sister site about arduino, see link on top right icon. Maybe they can help better

I have edited and added the code.

@Giacomo Catenazzi
I will do that for sure

Do not see how you define Serial1 on your UNO. And if you connect the GPS Module to RX TX it will interfere with the UNO`s USB Serial connection. Are you talking about garbage or losing accuracy?

Yes,I have used arduino awn serial converter (Rx And Tx pins and Max as a host) for communication And I works. But when I use arduino as the host it sends garbage data.I want to lower the baudrate of the GPS module it that possible?

I would be more than happy to have a command list or a command datasheet to configure and change the baudrate.

I got an example but I don't have an idea as to how am I going to send this message to the GPS module.

I got it working by reading the documentation and this code
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Create a software serial port on pins 10 (RX) and 11 (TX)
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(10, 11);

void setup() {
  // Start the software serial communication with the GPS module at 9600 baud (default for NEO-6M)
  Serial.begin(115200);
  gpsSerial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);  // Allow some time for the GPS module to initialize

  // Send the PUBX command to change the baud rate to 19200
  gpsSerial.println("$PUBX,41,1,0007,0003,19200,0*25");

  // Wait a moment for the command to take effect
  delay(1000);

  // Update the software serial to communicate at the new baud rate
  gpsSerial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
  // You can now communicate with the GPS module at 19200 baud
  if (gpsSerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(gpsSerial.read());  // Forward GPS data to Serial Monitor
  }
}

